# Nullpointer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Hi so my project is having a nullpointer when starting on emulator for some reason, i am not sure what the reason is. Here is the error i am getting :

```
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.panda.cleaner_batterysaver.ui.MainActivity.applyKitKatTranslucency(MainActivity.java:201)
W/System.err:     at com.panda.cleaner_batterysaver.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
```

Code parts:

```
private void applyKitKatTranslucency() {

        // KitKat translucent navigation/status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            setTranslucentStatus(true);
            SystemBarTintManager mTintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            mTintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            mTintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
            // mTintManager.setTintColor(0xF00099CC);

            mTintManager.setTintDrawable(UIElementsHelper
                    .getGeneralActionBarBackground(this));

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    UIElementsHelper.getGeneralActionBarBackground(this));

        }

    }
```

Drawable file where the method is called :

```
  public class UIElementsHelper {

    private static final String NOW_PLAYING_COLOR = "NOW_PLAYING_COLOR";
    private static final String BLUE = "BLUE";
    private static final String RED = "RED";
    private static final String GREEN = "GREEN";
    private static final String ORANGE = "ORANGE";
    private static final String PURPLE = "PURPLE";
    private static final String MAGENTA = "MAGENTA";
    private static final String GRAY = "GRAY";
    private static final String WHITE = "WHITE";
    private static final String BLACK = "BLACK";

    /**
     * Returns the ActionBar color based on the selected color theme (not used
     * for the player).
     */
    public static Drawable getGeneralActionBarBackground(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(0xFF9acd32);


        return drawable;

    }

}
```

Comment: What happened to the rest of the `getGeneralActionBarBackground` method?

Comment: updated with all of the code

Comment: Are you extending from Activity or AppCompatActivity? It is from AppCompatActivity try with getSupportActionBar.

Comment: Try to debug, what `getActionBar()` gives you as return value. You could have a NoActionbar style activated and have to manually add an actionbar.

Answer (score 2):

In your default styles.xml file, check what theme you are using. The default theme if you create an empty Activity is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

However, you may have used something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in which case you need to manually set the action bar like this in onCreate:

```
// Assuming you have a toolbar in your xml layout with id toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
                UIElementsHelper.getGeneralActionBarBackground(this));
}
```

If you are not using AppCompat then you will need to use getActionBar and an appropriate theme.